# jQuery .animate() acceleratation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have searched for an answer before this, but like most of my problems, I find nothing. :(

Basically I'm trying to make a custom jQuery image slider using a basic system:

1. Put all image paths into an array.
2. Pre-load all images using each array entry path.
3. Load HTML 'img's (left, center and right) with the array paths [0],[1](http://jsfiddle.net/RrQ5d/) and [2].
4. When you click left, all the images margin-left move to left by 100% (and vice versa for right)

Here's my problem; When I click one of the navigation buttons, the images move but NOT at the same speed, there's some kind of acceleration factor I can't seem to turn off, meaning there is a gap between the images when they move.

Anyone know why this happens and how to stop it?

I have another issue as well regarding this, should I make a separate question for this?

Here's the Javascript.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var images = [ "http://furrydex.net/img1.png", "http://furrydex.net/img2.png" ];
var loadedImages = [];
var pos = 0;
$.each(images, function( index, value ) {
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=value;
    loadedImages.push(img);
});
if(images[2] == undefined) {
    $('#left').attr('src', images[1]);
    $('#center').attr('src', images[0]);
    $('#right').attr('src', images[1]);
}
$('.navigationLeft').click(function() {
    console.log("yay");
    $( '.slide' ).animate({
        marginLeft: "100%"
    }, 500, "linear",  function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
});
```

The left black block is 'left' which you need to test it.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrQ5d/)

Comment: Please provide some code, or even better, a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. It's impossible for us to help you if we don't know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, it's late here, I'll get to it now.

Comment: JQuery animate functions usually have prefined transition which is not always "linear"..

Comment: @Alastor: Are you including jQuery UI (or certain other plugins)? It adds "easing" to animations. The purpose of easing is to make movement more natural; it would fit your description.

Comment: @SquareCat: Not "or". Provide the code, **in** the question. A fiddle is a nice "and."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder now happy?????????

Comment: I have added the javascript and a JSFiddle, also I have tried setting it to linear, but as you can see in the JSFiddle, there is still an overhead between them. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Hardy Thanks but it doesn't loop, this is key.

Comment: I do not understand the fiddle :/

Comment: Also I do not understand @Hardy's in-throw!?!

Comment: @dollarVar Oh darn sorry! The left black block is left... Sorry, all my base works look like this in WIP.

Comment: Just added my example since it works and this code doesn't.. also the performance is really good and works in mobile.. why so bad? I have seen more of-topic comments before..

Comment: Alastor, ok, I got the fiddle, and I can tell you so far (that's why I "did not get it first") that there is *no* (at least no *white*) gap between the pics, when the "Result" window is like very small :/

Comment: @dollarVar You think maybe using percentages is causing this?

Comment: Yeah, somehow, the gap gets larger over the way (try with 5000ms) :o

Comment: Darn, I don't know how to do it in pixels since animate() doesn't take inline functions, if it did i'd just use Left:(($(this).css('left', $(this).left() + 900)+"px");

Comment: You wouldn't need the `+"px"`, `left()` is no function and `$(this)` would be `.navigationLeft`...other than that it would work (y).

Comment: Welp, that's me put in my place :P I'm no jQuery guru mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I put something up, that makes it gapless, but I do think finding the culprit for making it somehow percentage-based-failing would be the right trick. ;)

```
var selWidth = $('.selector').width();

$( '.slide' ).animate({
  marginLeft: selWidth
})
```

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/RrQ5d/5/

Comment: Thank you :3 While this creates another issue (the window width is expanding) it does infact fix my problem. Not to sound rude I just want to ask, would this be an appropriate time to end this and accept the answer?

Comment: What, ehmm, no, the window width was expanding before!

Comment: Odd, it wasn't on me. Oh well.